# python server finished but not listening

Tags: python, server

I have created this server for a project of mine and it finishes with no errors, but I want it to listen for incoming connections here is the code

```
import socket
import sys
def socket_cr():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = ''
        port = 9999
        s= socket.socket()
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("socket creatin error " + (str(msg)))
socket_cr()
def socket_bind():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        print("binding to port :" + str(port))
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(5)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket binding error" + str(msg) + "\n" + "retrying")
        socket_bind()
def socket_acept():
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print("connection has been astablished | " + "IP" + address[0] + "| port" + str(address[1]))
def send_command(conn):
    while True:
        cmd = input()
        if cmd == 'quite':
            conn.close()
            s.close()
            sys.exit()
        if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
            conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
            client_response = str(conn.recv(1034), "utf-8")
            print(client_response, end="")
def main():
    socket_cr()
    socket_bind()
    socket_acept()
    main()
```

and the output is:

> Process finished with exit code 0

put it should be binding socket to port 9999

Comment: Ill add just small note since problem is solved, please try to avoid global keyword at all cost, it is bad practice, and it will bring you troubles, more info: http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has quite a few problems. If you don't mind, I will rewrite the whole code for you.
Revised code:

```
import socket
import sys

#No need to define functions for everything OR make the variables global every time.
try:
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 9999
    s = socket.socket()
except socket.error as msg:
    #You don't need to convert msg to a string since it's already a string. 
    print('Socket creating error '+ msg)

print('Binding to port: '+ str(PORT))
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print('Socket binding error '+msg+'\nRetrying.')
s.listen(5)
while True:
    conn, address = s.accept()
    # Address is not an iterable, you can't index elements in it. Address is the IP of the device you have just connected to.
    print('Connection has been established | IP '+ address)
    cmd = input()
    if cmd == 'quit':
        # You can end the connection with only a s.close()
        s.close()
        sys.exit()
        #encode is a method of a string, not a function.
        # Also, you have to specify how you want to encode the string e.g. mystring.encode('ascii')
        #Since it isn't specified, I'll assume it's ascii.
    if len(cmd.encode('ascii')) > 0:
        conn.send(cmd.encode('ascii'))
        # If the client is sending it encoded in ascii as well, instead of str(), you should decode it
        client_response = conn.recv(1034).decode('ascii')
        print(client_response, end='')
```

As you can see, defining functions for all of them is unnecessary and it makes the code unclean. Now, you should define the variables at the very beginning of the code if possible. And, you should make the host `0.0.0.0` to ensure public visibilty. 
Now, remember, that functions should not be overused.

Happy to help.

Comment: Thank you I am new to python and trying to use it for networking